# Modify CKEditor Advanced tab contents

Tags: tabs, ckeditor, customization

I'm using CKEditor and would like to modify the content of the Advanced tab

[image: advanced tab]

I'd only like the Style input to appear, any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it!

Here's some code to help you other guys out:

```
    CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
    // Take the dialog window name and its definition from the event data.
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    if (dialogName == 'link') {

        var advancedTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('advanced');
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
        var styleField = advancedTab.get('advStyle');
        advancedTab.remove();
        advancedTab.remove('advTitle');
        advancedTab.remove('advContentType');
        advancedTab.remove('advCSSClasses');
        advancedTab.remove('advCharset');
        advancedTab.remove('advRel');
        //var urlField = infoTab.get('url');
        //urlField['default'] = 'www.ireadhome.com'; //set default value for the url field
    }
});
```

Paste this code into your config.js. Hope it helps you out!